# In C, how do I "directly" copy a struct to an array member?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

So I want to do this:

```c
struct element{
  int t;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct element arr[10];
  arr[0]={3};
  return 0;
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:10: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
    7 |   arr[0]={3};
      |          ^
```

To fix this, I will have to resort to writing:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct element arr[10];
  struct element tmp = {3};
  arr[0]= tmp;
  return 0;
}
```

But I think it is inelegant to write a tmp value when I just want to assign directly to `element{3}`. How do I fix the syntax so that I do not need to create this `tmp` value?

Comment: BTW, `struct element tmp = element{3}` this is not valid C code. Though it is valid C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a **compound literal**:

```
arr[0]=(struct element){3};
```

Comment: The number of times I've seen ludicrous blocks of code written to do this very thing because the author(s) had no idea this feature existed in C just makes me cry.